# Is it normal for Laravel "wherenotin" statement to include null values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.6.7 with the SQL server driver connecting to SQL Server 2014.

When attempting the following query:

```
Warrant::where('vsStatus',632)
        ->whereNotIn('vsType',[-26927,-26929])
        ->whereNotIn('vsCategory',[-15723,-21708,-21708])
        ->where('Warrant.ORI','XXXXXXXXX')
        ->join('GlobalJacket','GlobalJacket.JacketID','=','Warrant.JacketID')
        ->where('GlobalJacket.JacketType','=',2)->get();
```

I am receiving back 2 results sets, where vsType = -19325 and where vsType = null

This is the query seen by the debugbar:

```
select * from [Warrant] inner join [GlobalJacket] on [GlobalJacket].[JacketID] = [Warrant].[JacketID] where [vsStatus] = '632' and [vsType] not in ('-26927', '-26929') and [vsCategory] not in ('-15723', '-21708', '-21708') and [Warrant].[ORI] = 'XXXXXXXXX' and [GlobalJacket].[JacketType] = '2'
```

And when pasting that directly into Management Studio 17 I am only getting the 1 result where vsType = -19325

Now I could easily include the null value into the 'whereNotIn' value list, however is this by design? All things consider 'null' is not in list, however why would MMS ignore the null value, but eloquent wouldn't?

Thanks for the help.